# Multiple queries in one ElasticSearch Query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Here an example of an item indexed in ES :

```
{
  "_id" : ..,
  "class": "A",
  "name": "item1"
}
```

I want a single query where I can get all items of the same class of the item with name "item1". So basically, I want all indexed items with class `A`, with only having the name.

I can do it with 2 queries :

Query 1 :

```
SEARCH
{
"query": {
   "query_string": {
       "default_field": "name",
            "query": "item1"
            }
        }
```

Then from this I get the class and I write this query :

```
SEARCH
{
"query": {
   "query_string": {
       "default_field": "class",
            "query": "A"
            }
        }
```

Any idea ? I know there's an easy way but I can't find it...

Comment: @ChandraPraneethN I really can't see how filters can help me. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple queries with clauses using a [`bool` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html). In this case, two criteria must be satisified, so both queries should be `must` clauses

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "item1",
            "fields": [
              "name"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "A",
            "fields": [
              "class"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't need relevancy scores, which it doesn't appear that you do in this case, both queries could be `filter` clauses instead of `must` clauses.

If `name` and `class` are mapped as [`keyword` datatypes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html), you may want to use a term-level query as opposed to a full-text query like `query_string` query. Here's what that would look like, using `filter` clauses

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name": {
              "value": "item1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "class": {
              "value": "A"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have the classe value `A`, I need to get it from the result of my first query.

Comment: OK. There's no way to pipe the output/_source of one query into another within the same request, so needs to be done with two queries. You can minimize the payload returned from the first query though with source filtering.